# Why my neo4j query insanely slow? How do i improve?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jrb

[image: Query Project]

Hi I am using neo4j for my production DB with 1800+ for this project node...
This is a screenshot from graphenedb on heroku.. Can anybody explain to me how do i improve my query so it didnt taking so long?

Answer (score 2):

Very probably you have no index for `:Project(status)` which causes a full label scan.

Otherwise it should be way less than 1s for only 1800 nodes.

Perhpas it was also the first query after db-start (or suspension) so it had to access disk.

Can you share a `PROFILE` screenshot of your query?

Comment: Hi i just know remember that i dont use any index on my property. And here is the screenshot insight for PROFILE is this what you mean? https://imgur.com/a/xZdNw

Comment: Seems highly likely that this answer should be marked as correct as it covers all the bases: option 1) you're missing indexes. option 2) The database wasn't properly warmed up. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the query itself.